# Gradle Could not resolve all dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying one simple thing: To import some of Google's libraries in order to use the Gmail API. I am aware that some of these jars do not exist on mavenCentral. I therefore updated my Google Repositories from the sdk manager and instructed gradle to look in the sdk. I also removed the version numbers in the end of the dependencies and replaced them with a + which did not resolve my problem and therefore fall back to the [original](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android#step_4_configure_the_project) `build.gradle` file.

My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()


        def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
        maven {
            url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/"
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hellobusiness.hotels"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0'
}
```

The error I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Hotels'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0/google-api-client-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0/google-api-client-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.20.0/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
     Required by:
         :Hotels:unspecified
   > Could not find com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-android/1.20.0/google-api-client-android-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-android/1.20.0/google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-android/1.20.0/google-api-client-android-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-android/1.20.0/google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar
     Required by:
         :Hotels:unspecified
   > Could not find com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-gson/1.20.0/google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-gson/1.20.0/google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.jar
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-gson/1.20.0/google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client-gson/1.20.0/google-api-client-gson-1.20.0.jar
     Required by:
         :Hotels:unspecified
   > Could not find com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev29-1.20.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev29-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev29-1.20.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev29-1.20.0.jar
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev29-1.20.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev29-1.20.0.pom
         file:/home/sanctus/adt/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev29-1.20.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev29-1.20.0.jar
     Required by:
         :Hotels:unspecified
```

I use eclipse with adt plugin and I use gradle from the command line

Comment: update this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'

Comment: please comment out compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0' this and check its effect

Comment: I updated the classpath you menthioned and I got a message prompting me to upgrate from gradle 2.1 that I had installed to 2.2. I did that and retrying to build. EDIT: I is being stuck to "Resolving dependencies" for like 10 minutes ...

Comment: Nope. Just got a `Build Failed` with the same dependencies missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this part in your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

These libraries are in Central Maven:

```
com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0.
com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0
com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0
```

About this library, I don't know where is.

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0
```

Also I suggest you using the version of:

- Android Studio 1.2.x
- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`
- gradle 2.4